# Having issues with FOV stretching when camera rotates vertically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem I'm having is that I have two different aim functions that have issues in one way or another

I'm trying to make a FPS in Unity3d, and I'm working on getting the camera and player movement aspects done. I've included my code below. My current object Hierarchy has Player as the parent, PlayerCam as it's child, and gun and BulletSpawnPoint as the child of PlayerCam.

In the function MouseAiming, it rotates the player's x and y axis's. When it rotates I don't experience stretching, but it causes my forward movement to allow the player to "fly" perse by just looking up and holding forward.

In the function MouseAiming2, I fixed the issue with the player's flight, but now I experience stretching or distortion when looking up/downwards.

I've tried searching online, but I can only find references to the code I used to create MouseAiming.

Here is the code relevant to the problem. I also added the movement function as it currently stands in case a solution could lay there instead.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private bool groundedPlayer;

    [Header("Player Movement")]
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 3000.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float turnSpeed = 4.0f;

    [Header("Camera Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject playerCamera;
    private float minTurnAngle = -90.0f;
    private float maxTurnAngle = 90.0f;
    private float rotX;
    private float rotY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MouseAiming2();
        Movement();
    }

    void MouseAiming()
    {
        float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed;
        rotX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed;

        rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, minTurnAngle, maxTurnAngle);

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotX, transform.eulerAngles.y + y, 0);
    }
    void MouseAiming2()
    {
        rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed;
        rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed;

        rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, minTurnAngle, maxTurnAngle);

        transform.Rotate(0, rotY, 0);

        playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles.x - rotX, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);

    }

    void Movement()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (rb.velocity.magnitude > 1)
        {
            rb.velocity.Normalize();
        }

        if (!groundedPlayer)
            return;

        if (Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player Jumpped");
            rb.AddForce(0f, jumpHeight, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            groundedPlayer = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (groundedPlayer)
            return;

        if (collision.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))
        {
            groundedPlayer = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After more experimentation, I learned that the issue comes from directly rotating the camera. If you rotate the object the camera is on, it doesn't change the field of vision, but if it's the camera being rotated it causes the "stretching" I was mentioning.